# Reload particular element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to reload particular element on button on click using jQuery, but when I click the button, the entire page gets loaded in this element. I have tried the following code which loads the entire page in this element. I want to load only particular element.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#button").click(function() {
        $("#demo").load(location.href + "#demo");
    });
});
```

```html
<div id="example">
    <p id="demo">hi</p>
    <button id="button" type="button">press</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use [`load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) with selector.

```
$("#demo").load(location.href + " #demo"); // Add space between URL and selector.
                                 ^
```

This will load only the `#demo` element from the `location.href` URL.

Answer (score 3):

You have to load the page using `$.get()` and extract the `#demo` fragment:

```
$("#button").click(function() {
  $.get(location.href).then(function(page) {
    $("#demo").html($(page).find("#demo").html())
  })
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Ajax, then create element with responseText, then put it into the div:

```
<head>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#button").click(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    url: location.href,
                    type:  'GET',
                    sucess: function(data)
                    {
                        refreshedPage = $(data);
                        newDemo = refreshedPage.find("#demo").html();
                        $('#demo').html(newDemo)
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="example">
       <p id="demo">hi</p>
       <button id="button" type="button">press</button>
    </div>
</body>
```

But You load the entire page, it might me not usefull. I suggest to make a php script which just returns the requested data, and call it via Ajax at page load and at button click...